# Stop UICollectionView from updating layout after deleteItems

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, cell

I have a collectionView with horizontal layout, where the selected cell should stay in the center of the screen.

My problem is,
if a cell, which is on the left side of the centered cell gets removed, the collectionView updates the layout and animates the remaining cells into position as needed, so that my currently selected cell, which should stay centered, moves one index to the left.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You can save position of cells:

```
var offsets = [IndexPath:CGFloat]()

public func getScrollPosition() -> CGFloat {
        return collectionView.contentOffset.x
    }
```

check if not centered cell deleted and set after delete cell.

```
collectionView.setScrollPosition(x: offsets[indexPath] ?? 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following function every time you delete an item in order to keep your selected item in the center. You can set scrollPosition to `.center`.

```
func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
               at scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, 
         animated: Bool)
```

For more information, you can check out this link [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618046-scrolltoitem)